# InstanceID.value() includes typename twice. Is it correct?

Tags: mongodb, javers

Is it correct, that InstanceId.value() includes the typename twice?

```
// gives "typename/...,typename'
public String value(){
    return this.getTypeName() + "/" + this.getCdoIdAsString();  
}

// gives comma-separated persistent values including typename
private String getCdoIdAsString(){
    return ReflectionUtil.reflectiveToString(this.cdoId); 
}
```

As a result for my custom type "StateStructures.Framework" with some Guid MongoRepository.queryForSnapshots() receives the following bson-query (and returns 0 results):

```
{ "globalId_key" : "StateStructures.Framework/49168d17-60e9-4720-97d2-a6f7928e18b6-0000,StateStructures.Framework"}
```

If I manually remove ",StateStructures.Framework" from the end then mongo returns the expected rows.

It looks like a bug: stating with typename in InstanceId.value() and appending it again in InstanceId.getCdoIdAsString() makes query definetely incorrect. 
Instead ignoring the typename during persistent fields iteration in InstanceId.getCdoIdAsString() seems to solve the bug.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer this question without knowing your domain classes (StateStructures and Framework). As far as I understand, you are using complex objects as Id?

Please post this classes and also details about objects being compared.
Do you use latest Javers version (1.4.0)?